# Copy constructor and dynamic memory

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I am a beginner in programming and I am learning about copy constructors. From different sources I can see that copy constructors are useful if I want to "deep copy" a class object so the new object's pointer members will point to new memory locations.

My question is, what is the advantage of defining the copy constructor as I do in class CopyCat in my example, if I get the same result with an empty copy constructor (as in class EmptyCat)?

My second question is, why do class Cat and class EmptyCat work differently? The only difference between them is that I define an empty copy constructor in EmptyCat. But as I run the program I can see that in EmptyCat after the copying the pointer member points to a new location while in class Cat it works as a shallow copy.

```
#include "iostream"

class Cat
{
  public:
    void GetMem() { std::cout << itsAge << "\n"; }
  private:
    int * itsAge = new int;
};

class EmptyCat
{
  public:
    EmptyCat() {}
    ~EmptyCat() {}
    EmptyCat(EmptyCat&obj) {}
    void GetMem() { std::cout << itsAge << "\n"; }
  private:
    int * itsAge = new int;
};

class CopyCat
{
  public:
    CopyCat() {}
    ~CopyCat() {}
    CopyCat(CopyCat&obj);
    int GetAge() { return *itsAge; }
    void GetMem() { std::cout << itsAge << "\n"; }
  private:
    int * itsAge = new int;
};

CopyCat::CopyCat(CopyCat & obj)
{
    itsAge = new int;
    *itsAge = obj.GetAge();
}

int main()
{
    Cat Garfield;
    Cat Kitty(Garfield);

    std::cout << "Memory addresses for the objects' <itsAge> member:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Garfield and Kitty (Class Cat):" << std::endl;
    Garfield.GetMem();
    Kitty.GetMem();

    EmptyCat Meow;
    EmptyCat Purr(Meow);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Meow and Purr (Class EmptyCat):" << std::endl;
    Meow.GetMem();
    Purr.GetMem();

    CopyCat Fluffy;
    CopyCat Felix(Fluffy);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Fluffy and Felix (Class CopyCat):" << std::endl;
    Fluffy.GetMem();
    Felix.GetMem();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the program I get this:

```
Memory addresses for the objects' <itsAge> member:
Garfield and Kitty (Class Cat):
00BBDA60
00BBDA60

Meow and Purr (Class EmptyCat):
00BB46A0
00BB8280

Fluffy and Felix (Class CopyCat):
00BB82B0
00BBE8A0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your class leaks memory, so it's not really a good example of anything.

Comment: I wanted to make it simple as possible, focusing on the copy constructor's behaviour

Comment: But by doing so you're missing everything that's interesting. If your destructor were to delete the allocation, you would immediately discover the rule of three and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what is the advantage of defining the copy constructor as I do in class CopyCat in my example, if I get the same result with an empty copy constructor (as in class EmptyCat)?

You don't get the same result. `CopyCat` allocates new memory *and* copies the value from the old class. The `EmptyCat` just allocates new memory, but does not copy the value.

> My second question is, why do class Cat and class EmptyCat work differently? The only difference between them is that I define an empty copy constructor in EmptyCat. But as I run the program I can see that in EmptyCat after the copying the pointer member points to a new location while in class Cat it works as a shallow copy.

In `Cat` you haven't declared a copy constructor, so the compiler will generate one when needed. The default copy constructor does a member-wise copy from the original. In your case, this will copy the pointer (so that it stores the same address as the original).

In the `EmptyCat` you have a user defined copy constructor. But as that one doesn't handle the pointer member, its default value will be used.

```
int * itsAge = new int;
```

This is what allocates a new `int` and gets you a different pointer value.

Comment: Based on your answer I made some changes and I managed to present how the emptily defined copy constructor works.
Copy constructor with empty definition is not a copy constructor actually, it copies nothing, it works actually as a new object creation. It creates a new object based on the class definition, and that is why I got confused, because I had the `int * itsAge = new int;` statement in the class definition (so based on that the empty copy constructor allocated new memory for the new object).

Comment: I made some further research and I found out that the so called implicit copy constructor (which one is used when there is no declared copy constructor) is equivalent to this:
`Class::Class (const Class& object):
x(object.x), y(object.y), z(object.z)
{}`

So the implicit copy constructor does more than an emptily defined one.

Answer (score 2):

Deep copying and shallow copying is rather a C concept, where you have only structures and raw pointers. A pointer can be owned, in which case the copy must be deep, or it can be shared, in which case the copy is shallow (and you have to be careful about freeing it if it's allocated with malloc).

In C++, new is now effectively deprecated. We have unique pointers, which are "owning pointers" and "shared pointers". However pointers are relatively rare. Array members of classes are std::vectors, string members are std::strings. And copies are automatically deep, (You use a reference if you want a shallow copy).

Pointers are held back for relatively unusual situations, like trees and graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the same behavior with and without an empty copy constructor. `EmptyCat(EmptyCat& obj) { }` does absolutely nothing.

```
CopyCat(CopyCat& obj) {
  itsAge = new int;
  *itsAge = obj.GetAge();
}
```

dynamically allocates a new `int` and assigns to it a value from the `obj`.